# what log rule is applied to do this swap?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

What logarithm rule is applied that allows you to write $3^{\log_4n} = n^{\log_43}$?

Comment: Taking $\log_4$ of both sides gives $\log_43\log_4 n=\log_4 n\log_4 3$  Start from there, and raise $4$ to both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the change of base formula, we have
$$\log_4 n = {\log_3 n\over \log_3 4}$$
and plugging this in on the left hand side, we get
$$3^{\log_4 n} = n^{1/\log_3 4} = n^{\log_4 3}.$$
The fact that $\log_b a = 1/\log_a b$ can be proven from the change of base formula as well.

Answer (score 2):

For any $a$ and $b,$ $a^b = (e^{\ln a})^b = e^{b\ln a}$ and $a^{\log_a b} = b \to \log_a b \cdot \ln a = \ln b \to \log_a b =  \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}.$

(These work in any base but I work with the natural log for convenience.)

So, $$a^{\log_b c} = a^{\frac{\ln c}{\ln b}} = e^{\frac{\ln a \ln c}{\ln b}} = c^{\frac{\ln{a}}{\ln b}} = c^{\log_b a}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using $4$ as a $\log$ base,

$$3 = 4^{\log_43},\quad n = 4^{\log_4 n}.$$

Then by applying some exponent rules (that ${(a^b)}^c = a^{bc}$),

$$3^{\log_4n} = 4^{(\log_43)(\log_4 n)} = 4^{(\log_4n)(\log_4 3)} = n^{\log_4 3}.$$